# How to output a list elements as multi line output (each element in new line). Also the length of list is variable depending on the input chosen

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I am trying to output list  in multi line format (each element in new line) and the list size is variable dependent on the input.
[My sample dataframe that I am using for this exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mxu5.png)

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Employee-skills.xlsx')
df.to_csv ("Employee-skills.csv", 
                  index = None,
                  header=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("Employee-skills.csv"))

app=dash.Dash()

emp_options = []
for emp in df['First-Last Name'].unique():
    emp_options.append({'label':str(emp),'value':emp})
skill_options=[]
for skill in df.columns[1:]:
    skill_options.append({'label':str(skill),'value':skill})

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(children=[dcc.Dropdown(id='skill-picker',options=skill_options,placeholder='Select Skills',value=[" "],multi=True),
                       html.Br(),
                        html.Div(id='skill-out')],style={'width':'48%', 'display':'inline-block'}),
    
    html.Div([dcc.Dropdown(id='employee-picker',options=emp_options,placeholder='Select Employee')],
             style={'width':'30%', 'float':'right','display':'inline-block'}),
    
    
])

@app.callback(    Output('skill-out','children'),
    [Input('skill-picker','value')])

def skill_query(skillset):
    if skillset==" ":
        return " "
    else:
        cols=[i for i in skillset]
        new_df=df.copy()
        new_df[cols]=new_df[new_df[cols]>0][cols]
        new_df=new_df.dropna()
        return "\n".join(new_df['First-Last Name'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

[inline output I am currently seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFY2Y.png)

[I want output to be something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YBo0.png)